# How to include strings in dplyr mutate experssions?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is the result I'd like to have
`ddf = data.frame(a=1:5,b = 10:14)`
`ddf %>% mutate(pr = a)`

However, I would like to have a string variable
`v = 'a'`
that will replace 'a' in mutate. Something like:
`ddf %>% mutate(pr = v)`

The expression above doesn't do what I want and I am wondering if there is something else that will work.

The only way I could achieve that is

```
ddf = data.frame(a=1:5,b = 10:14)
v = 'a'
expr=paste0('ddf %>% mutate(pr = ',v,')')
eval(parse(text=expr))
```

Is there any "true" dplyr way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
ddf %>% mutate(pr = !!sym(v))
```

This gives the same input shown in your example:

```
a  b pr
1 10  1
2 11  2
3 12  3
4 13  4
5 14  5
```